# How do you formally construct the following proof regarding completeness and vector spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $S$ denote the vector space of all finitely nonzero sequences; that is, $X =(X_n) \in S$ if $X_n = 0$ for all but finitely many n. Show that $S$ is not complete under the sup norm $\| X \|_\infty = \sup_n |X_n|$.

---

What I have so far is that is $S$ is vector space of finitely non-zero sequence then $t_n(k)=1/2^k$   where $k=1, 2, 3$... I know that the norm is also the same as the norm of $L_\infty$. If I take the limit of $t_n$ as $k$ goes to infinity,  then it converges to $0$. I think  $\|t_n\|=1/i^2$. I am not sure how all of this tells me that $S$ is not complete under the particular Sup norm.

Answer (score 1):

Try these $t_n(k) = 1/2^k$ if $0\le k \le n$ and $0$ otherwise. This is uniformly Cauchy but it does not converge in your vector space.

Comment: Using tn(k)=1/2^k, for k=1,2,3... If I were to take the limit of tn(k) as k goes to infinity, I can see that {1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, ...} gets closer and closer to 0. By definition, completeness is when every Cauchy sequence converges to a point M. I'm having trouble seeing why it does not converge in this vector space.

Comment: Careful: there are two levels of convergence being discussed here.